# Limit to a single block when looping through Wagtail paragraph streamfield Items?

Tags: django, wagtail

I have added 4 paragraph blocks in a streamfields. When looping over the paragraph block, it show all 4 paragraph in separate

tags. How can I only limit it to the first paragraph block?
I tried using this solution:

```
{% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}
 <p>{{block.value}}</p>
{% endif %}
```

But the problem was that its only possible when the paragraph field is placed in the first order. For example, there can be 3 images before the first paragraph which makes the possible solution void.

**blog/models.py**

```py
class BlogPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
    ])
    
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body')
    ]
```

**blog_page.html**

```html
{% for block in page.body %}
  {% if block.block_type == 'paragraph' %}
    <p>{{block.value.0}}</p>  <!-- Another attempt at trying to get single paragraph -->
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often easier to do this sort of logic in Python code inside the model, rather than trying to shoehorn it into Django template notation:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
    ])

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body')
    ]

    def first_paragraph(self):
        for block in self.body:
            if block.block_type == 'paragraph':
                return block.value
```

Then use `<p>{{page.first_paragraph}}</p>` in your template.

Comment: Incredible! Didn't know you could do that. So you can create any custom function inside a class and call it with the Django templates .Thanks.